# Semi border around div

Tags: html, css

I am new with CSS and I need help:-
I want the semi border at some positions in div as shown in the image. Can some tell me how to do that.

[image: Semi Border]

Comment: If my answer helped, please consider marking it as accepted :)

Answer (score 4):

You use a `<fieldset>` and the HTML element `<legend>`

See example below

```css
fieldset {
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Contact:</legend>
  Name:<input type="text">
  <br>
  Email:<input type="text">
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can apply a border around the container and fill the background of the text so the outline is cut off like this:

```html
<html>
  <style>
    #text {
      position: absolute;
      background: white;
      top: -15px;
      left: 10px;
      padding: 5px;
    }
    #con {
      margin: 20px;
      width: 300px;
      height: 500px;
      position: relative;
      border: 5px solid red;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <div id="con">
       <div id="text"> SEMI BORDER ? </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```